# Help me to find out this integration $\int \frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to find this math by integrating by parts but I am unable to do it.
$$\int \frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}dx$$

Comment: What have you tried? Did you partial fractions it?

Comment: Yes I am trying by parts

Comment: I said "partial fractions", not "integrate by parts". Separately, do you know what is $ \int \log \frac{1}{1-x}$?

Comment: Is this how the formula should look? Please use Mathjax to format your expressions

Comment: No I didn't know partial fractions.

Comment: If you know how to solve this math please help me.

Comment: try to solve $\int \dfrac{logx}{2(1-x)} dx+\int \dfrac{logx}{2(1+x)}dx$, note that when you add the two integrals and do some operations, you return to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use partial fraction decomposition to split.

$$\int \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x}dx + \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}dx$$

Then using integration by parts for each. For the first, choose to integrate $\frac{1}{1+x}dx$ and to differentiate $\ln(x)$. Similarly for the other, integrate $\frac{1}{1-x}dx$ and  differentiate $\ln(x)$.

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)\ln(1+x) - \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx -\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)\ln(1-x) + \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx$$

Now, for the two integrals left, both can be manipulated to be in the form of $-\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx = \mathrm{Li_2}(x) + C$, where $\mathrm{Li_2}(x)$ is the dilogarithm function. Thus we have,

$$\int \frac{\ln(x)}{1-x^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln(x)\ln(1+x) -\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)\ln(1-x) + \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Li_2}(-x) - \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Li_2}(x) + C$$.

Hopefully answering your question.

Comment: Can you explain me more about dilogarithm function. Thank in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The dilogarithm function is a special function that exists for many reasons, but one of them being because the integral $\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx$ is nonelementary. Note that it’s pretty close to $\int \frac{\ln(x)}{x}dx$, which is elementary and can be integrated via the substitution $u=\ln(x)$. Note that elementary basically means/implies that its integral can be expressed in standard mathematical notation, and nonelementary being the opposite. There’s more here about the specific dilogarithm function, and its family, the polylogarithm:

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm